# How do i have individual links after loading my content into a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am loading a div #content with external urls. The address bar stays the same, is there a way to keep loading the urls into the div and also have individual links people can copy and paste and share? This is an example of where i am at right now [www.lariverola.net](http://www.lariverola.net)

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu a').click(function() {
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));

      return false; 
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Use hash or history api. See this: http://html5demos.com/history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu').on("click","a",function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));

      return false; 
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, i tried using this but it doesn't seem to be working, instead of opening in the div its loading a new page.

http://lariverola.net/test1.html

http://lariverola.net